# Review task bug

Tags: bug

This is happening a lot to me and its really getting on my nerves.

I'll log on and next to the review list will be a 3 in that orangey brown box which should indicate that there are 3 things waiting for review:

[image]

However when I click on it there usually is nothing there:

[image]

The box won't go away and it only ever shows a three.

> How can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah. That indicator has pretty much always been broken, or at best working in a not entirely intuitive way. There's plenty of posts on main meta about it.